# How do I make Angular Material's button toggle full width but left-align its contents?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a Tree of Button Toggles in a Button Toggle Group:

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
    <mat-button-toggle-group [ngModel]="selectedElement" (ngModelChange)="select($event)">
        <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
            <li class="mat-tree-node">
                <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
                <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
                <mat-button-toggle class="selectable" [value]="node.ref">
                    <mat-icon class="type-icon">
                        {{getDisplayIcon(node.ref.type)}}
                    </mat-icon>
                    {{node.name}}
                </mat-button-toggle>
            </li>
        </mat-tree-node>
        <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
        <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
            <li>
                <div class="mat-tree-node">
                    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                        </mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-button-toggle class="selectable" [value]="node.ref">
                        <mat-icon class="type-icon">
                            {{getDisplayIcon(node.ref.type)}}
                        </mat-icon>
                        {{node.name}}
                    </mat-button-toggle>
                </div>
                <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
                    <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </mat-nested-tree-node>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
</mat-tree>
```

It works, but each button toggle has a different width based on the size of its contents:

[image]

I can make each button full width by adding this to my `.scss` file:

```css
.selectable {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Which works, but all of them are centered rather than left-aligned (and the really long one goes beyond):

[image]

I've narrowed the problem down to this `span` that is generated by `mat-button-toggle` and surrounds my contents and has `display: inline-block`:

[image]

Adding `width: 100%` to this `span` lets me add a flex box to the contents and align them properly, but I can't change the span in Angular because it's not my component. I also can't style the `mat-button-toggle` to align content to the left, as the child `button` element is full width. How do I get it to do what I want?

Comment: Have you tried to add your button style in the app style.css?

Comment: I thought I had, but I think I was out of my depth at the time. I went back and tried it, and it worked. This is what I added to my app `styles.css`:

`mat-button-toggle.selectable button span {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Francesco Lisandro pointed out, I could use my app's styles.css to modify the element I wouldn't normally be able to. This is what I added:

```css
mat-button-toggle.selectable button span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
}
```